# Move model method to helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, helper

I have 3 models with the same method. To stay DRY I'd like to move these to helper method but not sure how to make it global but still receive from model.

Currently I have `format_slug` in 3 models.

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :format_slug

  def format_slug
    slug.parameterize.downcase
  end
end
```

How to move `format_slug` to application_helper and call method through before filter in model?

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def format_slug(model)
    model.slug.parameterize.downcase
  end
end

class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :format_slug
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wouldn't want to use a **helper**, but you could use another **module**.   Helpers are used in the views, and this is something that is happening exclusively in your model.

This is a good candidate for a concern, you can find more about that here
https://gist.github.com/dhh/1014971

(This could be in lib/sluggable.rb or app/models/concerns/sluggable.rb)  The latter will be  standard in Rails 4, but be sure to adjust your load paths.

```
module Sluggable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_save :format_slug
  end

  def format_slug
    slug.parameterize.downcase
  end
end
```

Then in your models where you want to use it:

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Sluggable
end
```

Comment: Thanks @shawn-balestracci Time to get used to Rails 4 standards

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to drier your code.

#### Method 1: Using helper

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def format_slug(str)
    str.parameterize.downcase
  end
end

class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
   before_save :handle_slug

   def handle_slug
     format_slug self.slug
   end
 end
```

#### Method 2: Extend ActiveRecord

```
# lib/my_ar_extension.rb
module MyArExtension
  def format_slug
    self.slug.parameterize.downcase if self.slug
  end
end

ActiveRecord::base.send :include, MyArExtension

# Page model
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :slug # and others
  before_filter :format_slug
  # other code
end
```

Comment: Thanks @billy-chan I'll save it for later. For now I'm gonna use concerns.